# DRF: Non-Model serializer doesn't work with Non-Model Class

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using djangorestframework==3.3.2 with Python 2.7.11+

I have data in json that represent instances of this class:

```
class APITransaction(object):

    def __init__(self, created_on):  #several_other_attrs
        self.created_on = parser.parse(created_on)  # this is Never called
        # ... several other fields

    @staticmethod
    def create(attributes_json):
        return APITransaction(attributes_json.get('createdOn'), ... )
```

The serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    created_on = serializers.DateTimeField()
    # ... more fields here

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return APITransaction.create(**validated_data)   # why isn't this called?

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        raise NotImplemented
```

Now I am trying to use that serializer from:

```
class TransactionView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer   # probably useless

    def list(self, request):
         # ...
         serializer = MySerializer(list_of_json, many=True)
         return Response(serializer.data)
```

where `list_of_json` is a list of json representing `APITransaction` class.

Unfortunately I am getting a `'unicode' object has no attribute 'isoformat'` error caused by the fact that the `APITransaction.create` is never called thus the `parser.parse` inside `APITransaction.__init__` is never used to cast the string.

I know this is not the correct way to user Serializers, but DRF docs don't mention anything about what you should do when you have non-ORM classes.

Any Ideas on how I could use the Serializer? When I have only one instance, I am able to explicitly build `APITransaction` object and then pass it on `MySerializer`, but when I have multiple inside json, isn't an automatic way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

> APITransaction.create is never called

You are serializing data. `create` will only be called during deserialization so it's expected not to be called.

Note that `list` is a safe method that should not create data.
`Viewset`'s `create` is probably what you want. Moreover, you'll need to validate the data and save the serializer.

You should probably go through the [step 1 of the  Django REST framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) and the [working with serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#working-with-serializers) in particular.

Comment: Actually I am deserializing data , what I needed to use, in order create to be called, was `serializer.save()`

Comment: You need more than just that: calling is_valid, saving and *NOT* using .data (validated_data or the save's result).